# Validating Arrays not working in laraval 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Validating Arrays not working in laraval 9.

Request as follows

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "nic" => "908110248V"
    "employee_id" => "1"
    "request_id" => "2"
    "schedule_training_id" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "nic" => "962930898v"
    "employee_id" => "2"
    "request_id" => "1"
    "schedule_training_id" => "1"
  ]
]
```

validator code snipit as follows

```
        $validator = Validator::make($request->input('data_attributes'), [
            'data_attributes.*.nic' => 'required|max:9'
            
        ]);
```

Comment: there is no key named 'data_attributes' that you are passing to `make` ... you are passing a 0-indexed array with 2 elements to `make` so the inputs are named '0' and '1' ... you would need to be passing an associative array with a key of 'data_attributes` to `make` to have an "input" named 'data_attributes'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
$validator = Validator::make($request->input('data_attributes'), [
            
       '*.nic' => 'required|max:9'
            
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the matrix as a whole and then start working with its elements, this is an example of what you should do:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->input('data_attributes'), [
    "data_attributes"    => "required|array|min:3",
    "data_attributes.*"  => "required|string|distinct|min:3",
]);
```